# API for metrics per Azure Site instance

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, metrics

In Azure's Portal you can view instance specific metrics per site if you go to a **resource**, select **Metrics per instance (Apps)**, select the tab **Site Metrics** and then click an individual instance (starting with `RD00...` in the screenshot below):

[image]

I'd like to get this data (per instance, including the instance name `RD00...`) using some REST API call. I've looked at [Azure's Resource Manager](https://resources.azure.com/) and their [Metrics API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/azure/dn931943.aspx), but couldn't find a way to get this data.

Is this possible, and, if so, how/where can I get this data?

Comment: This Metrics per instance options seem to have been removed from the Web Apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've looked at Azure's Resource Manager and their Metrics API, but couldn't find a way to get this data.

Based on the [supported metrics with Azure Monitor of websites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftwebsites-including-functions), Azure Metrics API only supports total and average type metrics for Azure Web App. We can't get per instance metrics by Azure Metrics API.

If you turn on the Web server logging in Azure portal, you will get the detail request data from /LogFiles/http/RawLogs/ folder using FTP. You could download the log and generate the metrics according the log.

Following is a record of raw logs. The ARRAffinity property will specify which instance is used to handle user request.

```
2017-04-27 08:51:32 AMOR-WEBAPP-TESTMSBUILD GET /home/index X-ARR-LOG-ID=bbdf4e53-3b96-4884-829c-cf82554abcc7 80 - 167.220.255.28 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.79+Safari/537.36+Edge/14.14393 ARRAffinity=8f8ac6c076f7a9e2132f2eea1ff0fc61836fde1fef8c5525da0e81359003c9e8;+_ga=GA1.3.411824075.1493282866;+_gat=1 - amor-webapp-testmsbuild.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 2607 1145 10095
```

*ARRAffinity=8f8ac6c076f7a9e2132f2eea1ff0fc61836fde1fef8c5525da0e81359003c9e8*