# What happened to metrics per instance on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Azure webapps had a metrics per instance option in the monitoring group which today have disappeared.  This allowed to look at the memory and cpu usage of a specific app within an app service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/05/01/april-2017-app-service-update/), the troubleshooting tools(include Metrics per Instance (Apps)) has now moved into Diagnose and Solve problems.

You could find them in Diagnose and Solve problems as below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you...I've been searching online and could not find this anywhere.  I'll follow that blog from now on.

Comment: That "Tools" section doesn't seem to exist. I had to follow brianheinle's instructions.

Comment: Ok, I found them. These tools only exist under the WEB APP's "Diagnose and solve problems" section, and not under the same section for the App Service.

Answer (score 3):

I too was disappointed to see this was removed/moved.  The only way I now know how to access this page is:

Go into your App Service Plan > Diagnose and Solve Problems > Under "Solutions to common problems" expand "My app is low on CPU" > Click the link to "CPU/Memory" and it will take you to the Metrics Per Instance (ASP) page.

I hope this is not a permanent solution, or hopefully I am just overlooking the "easy" way to get to this now.  If anyone has a better way, please share!

Hope this helps!

Brian

Comment: Well, I see now that Brando's directions work great, I was overlooking something here. Anyway, now you have another backdoor.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for this. Why are they hiding one of the most useful tools on App Service?

Comment: I wish I knew!  Our app has been having serious CPU issues since moving to Azure, which did not exist on our other environments, so them hiding the main tool to see server CPU is a pain, if anything I would think they would have made it better and brought it to the forefront as a dashboard graph...

Answer (score 3):

As of November 2019 you have to use "Apply splitting" under Monitoring > Metrics.

[image: Screenshot from the Azure Portal]

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking at the Monitoring tile of your ***web app*** resource.  Look in the Monitoring tile of your ***app service plan*** your web app is running on and you will see the CPU and Memory metrics.

Comment: There is no Monitoring group on the App Service Plan.  There is a chart on the Overview that shows total CPU and Memory.  The question is regarding the "Mertrics per instance" that was available until recently in the Web App Monitoring group.  It allowed us to see memory and CPU for each specific WebApp in the App Service Plan.  See this questions for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643832/api-for-metrics-per-azure-site-instance/43654717